# LINQ - Flatten nested sequence so it is joined with the parent sequence

Tags: c#, linq

I need to make a new sequence (preferably using linq) that lists a type and all of the interfaces it implements.

Here is an example:

```
public interface ITypeA { }
public interface ITypeB { }
public interface ITypeC { }

public class Class1 { }
public class Class2 : ITypeA, ITypeB, ITypeC { }
public class Class3 : ITypeC, ITypeA { }

var specializedContents = new object[] { new Class1(), new Class2(), new Class3() };
```

I am trying to make a sequence that looks like this.

```
------------------------------------------------------
| Type          |  Interface                         |
------------------------------------------------------
| Class2        |  ITypeA                            |
| Class2        |  ITypeB                            |
| Class2        |  ITypeC                            |
| Class3        |  ITypeC                            |
| Class3        |  ITypeA                            |
------------------------------------------------------
```

I understand that I need to use `[instance].GetType()` for the first column and `[instance].GetType().GetInterfaces()` for the second column, but I am having trouble working out how to *expand* the first column and make it line up with the second one. I have looked quite a bit, but I can only find methods for wrapping up a sequence into an inner list, but couldn't find a way to unwrap a pre-existing one into an outer list.

I looked at the .SelectMany() method (from [this post](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2008/10/10/use-linqs-selectmany-method-to-flatten-collections/)) and it feels like I am on the right track, but I can't seem to work out exactly how to make the query work.

So, how do I make this type of list using LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
from x in specializedContents
let t = x.GetType()
from i in t.GetInterfaces()
select new { Type = t.Name, Interface = i.Name };
```

Answer (score 1):

`SelectMany` is indeed a reasonable way to do it. You could encode the Type/Interface pairs as a `Tuple`, or as @david.s shows, as an anonymous type.

```
var specializedContents = new object[] { ... };

var typeInterfacePairs = specializedContents.Select(o => o.GetType())
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetInterfaces().Select(i => Tuple.Create(t, i)));

// or

var typeInterfaceObjs = specializedContents.Select(o => o.GetType())
    .SelectMany(t =>
        t.GetInterfaces().Select(i => new { Type = t, Interface = i }));
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I need to support .NET 3.5 so Tuple is not an option. Your second solution would work, but I prefer the query syntax to functions.

Comment: @NightOwl888: That's fair - as you may guess, I personally prefer the method syntax, although I wasn't even aware of the `let x = ...` form in the query syntax. I'll probably be doing some reading on it now...

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different than a truly flat list, but potentially useful would be to shove everything into a dictionary.

```
var dict = specializedContents.Select(o => o.GetType())
                              .ToDictionary(k => k.Name, v => v.GetInterfaces());
```

It's still easy to display in the manner you want using something like below, but the intermediate structure might still be valuable.

```
foreach(var kvp in dict)
{
    foreach(var value in kvp.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("| {0} | {1} |", kvp.Key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't trying to display it - I was trying to join it again to a sorted list of interfaces so I could sort and group the results by interface before my program processes them. However, the join wouldn't work without flattening the list first.